# Why does the for loop statemet don't work in django template

Tags: javascript, django, for-loop

I'm trying to make a chart in my django app for that I'm using this code of javascript in my template:

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Acceuil {% endblock title %}
<!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card ">
                        <div class="card-header ">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Statistics</h4>
                         </div>
                        <div class="card-body ">
                            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [    {% for x in clients % }'{{ x.name }}',{ % endfor %}   ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Nbr des factures',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]},
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }] }
    }});});
</script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

And this is my view

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['Comptable'])
def home(request):
    clients=Client.objects.all()
    context= {'clients':clients}
    
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

And I get the error **'for ' statement should use the format 'for x in y': for x in clients%}'{{x.name}}',{%endfor** although I think that I'm using the right format.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. There is some typo in your code.

```
[    {% for x in clients %} '{{ x.name }}', {% endfor %}   ],
```